# What is a data structure suited for representing railways with turnouts?

Tags: algorithm, go, data-structures

I'm trying to represent the paths in a railroad as a data structure but I am having a hard time representing turnouts.

This feels like a graph problem, but there is a difference compared to regular graphs.
A railway turnout is a vertex connected to three other vertices. A, B and C. 
But, in a railway system the graph is traversed with a direction.
So, you are able to take the path B -> turnout -> A and C -> turnout -> A, but are not able to take the path B -> turnout -> C.

Is there a (graph) data structure which allows for representing paths with directions?

This data structure  would provide the base for a software system to automate a small model railroad.

Comment: Turnout itself is not 3 vertices - it's a single vertex. Each terminal or turnout is a vertex, and every continuous piece of railway without turnouts is edge

Comment: You are right, representing a turnout as one vertex with three edges is better. Thank you, I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can represent the turnout as 2 vertices - one for each state of the turnout. So if you have source `A` and destinations `B` and `C` and turnout which can switch between `B` and `C` - you will have 2 vertices for this turnout: `TB` and `TC`. Also you will have following edges: `A->TB`, `TB->B`, `A->TC`, `TC->C`

This allows you to travel from `A -> TB -> B` and from `A -> TC -> C`. And since you will have **no edge** between `TB` and `TC` - you will not be able to travel from `B -> C` directly

Comment: I think the question was how to represent this in a `go` struct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give a psuedo code example of how this would work? Since I do not yet how this wouldn't make it so it's still traversable from B -> TB -> A -> TC -> C.

Answer (score 2):

Each path can be considered as a vertice and a connection between two paths as an edge.

B ->
        A
C ->

This can be represented as a graph in a Go map,

Take a look at the following,
In your example directional connection exists from B -> A and C -> A. This can be represented in a map as follows.

```
graph := map[string][]string{
    "B": []string{"A"},
    "C": []string{"A"},
}
```

Each key in the map represents the starting path of a directional connection. Each value in the array of the corresponding key is the destination path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case, how would you structure it so it is also traversable from A to B and from A to C. Because, if I add an entry to the map `"A": []string{"B", "C"}`, it's not defined in the data structure that you're not allowed to go back to C when you arrive at A coming from B. Am I not mistaken?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I think you need to manage that based on the state(where the train came from last time). You cannot have that information in a simple data structure.